# What is the Feature vector size of Haar cascade frontal face detection in XML file?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, face-detection, feature-extraction

What is the Feature vector size of Haar cascade frontal face detection in XML file? I want to know the size of Feature vector of the generated XML File in OpenCV.
Is there any way to find the size of feature vector in all the available haar cascade XML files in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the generated XML file with a text editor, you can see the number of features used for each stage of the cascade with the tag:

```
<maxWeakCount>
```

You can also get the information about each unique features used by looking at the tag (at the end of the file):

```
<features>
```

For example with the file `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml`, with a rapid word count I get the number of 2094 unique features used in the cascade of classifiers.